# Read mixed type lines from file

Tags: c++, parsing, input

Being given an input file formatted as following:

```
0 1 Hello world!
1 2 Stack Overflow is a very useful website.
```

I have to parse it into an array of following structure:

```
struct Message {
    int source; //eg. 0
    int dest; //eg. 1
    std::string content; // eg. "Hello world!\n"
}
```

But I am in a lack of good looking code for this.

My current solution is reading file line by line and then parse it using sscanf:

My current solution is to read every line of the file and then parse it using sscanf:

```
std::ifstream f("input");
int src, dest;
char line[1000], text[1000];
while(getline(f, line, 1000)) {
    sscanf(line, "%d%d,%999[^\n]", &src, &dest, text);
    // Process the values
}
```

What I dislike about it is that it is mixing iostream reading with stdio sscanf. Also, in my program the space after the 2nd integer and the \n character at the end of line should be part of the text. I work around it using appends, but I am pretty sure there is a more effective solution.

Can you give me an idea about how to do that in C++ without a cumbersome code?

Thank you!

Comment: As much as I hate to do this, but "[What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)"

Comment: Have you looked at these: [read file c++ structure](https://www.google.com/search?q=StackOverflow+c%2B%2B+read+file+structure&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::ifstream f("input");

    int src, dst;
    char line[1000] = {0};
    while (f >> src >> dst) {
        f.get(line, 1000, '\n');
        std::cout << src << ' ' << dst << line << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to create a working code, which successfully loads data from file directly into a given structure. In order to do that, you must 1) create file either via another function, or manually from file explorer's level, 2) data has to be ordered in the same manner like in the structure, 3) to avoid any problems related to faulty data read, plant one struct's element per line.

I'll give you my own example I was working on for the last few hours.

**"character.h" header file**

```
#ifndef CHARACTER_H
#define CHARACTER_H
#include <iostream>

class Character {
public:
    struct CharacterParameters {
        std::string name;
        std::string race;
        std::string playerClass;
        double height;
        double weight;
        int age;
    };
    struct CharacterStatistics {
        double maxHealth;
        double currentHealth;
        double maxStamina;
        double currentStamina;
        double maxCarryWeight;
        double currentCarryWeight;
        double currentCharacterWeight;
        double basicHealthRegen;
        double basicStaminaRegen;
        double healthRegenBonus;
        double staminaRegenBonus;
        double maxSpeed; // modified by items
        double currentSpeed;
        double currentForce;
        double basicAcceleration;
        double modifiedAcceleration; // currentCharacterWeight * currentSpeed / currentCharacterWeight
    };
    Character::CharacterParameters cpInstance;
    Character::CharacterStatistics csInstance;
    static void CreateNewPlayer();
    static void DisplayCurrentSettings();
    static void SaveDataToFile();
    static void ReadDataFromFile();
private:

};
#endif
```

**"character.cpp" file**

```
<code ommited>
    Character * newPlayer = new Character;
    void Character::ReadDataFromFile() {
        Character::CharacterParameters cpInstance;
        Character::CharacterStatistics csInstance;
        ifstream playerData;
        playerData.open("playerData.txt");
        playerData >> newPlayer->cpInstance.name;
        playerData >> newPlayer->cpInstance.race;
        playerData >> newPlayer->cpInstance.playerClass;
        playerData >> newPlayer->cpInstance.height;
        playerData >> newPlayer->cpInstance.weight;
        playerData >> newPlayer->cpInstance.age;
        playerData >> newPlayer->csInstance.maxHealth;
        playerData >> newPlayer->csInstance.currentHealth;
        playerData >> newPlayer->csInstance.maxStamina;
        playerData >> newPlayer->csInstance.currentStamina;
        playerData >> newPlayer->csInstance.maxCarryWeight;
        playerData >> newPlayer->csInstance.currentCarryWeight;
        playerData >> newPlayer->csInstance.currentCharacterWeight;
        playerData >> newPlayer->csInstance.maxSpeed;
        playerData >> newPlayer->csInstance.currentSpeed;
        playerData >> newPlayer->csInstance.basicAcceleration;
        playerData >> newPlayer->csInstance.currentForce;
        playerData >> newPlayer->csInstance.modifiedAcceleration;
        playerData >> newPlayer->csInstance.basicHealthRegen;
        playerData >> newPlayer->csInstance.basicStaminaRegen;
        playerData >> newPlayer->csInstance.healthRegenBonus;
        playerData >> newPlayer->csInstance.staminaRegenBonus;
        playerData.close();
    }
```

**"playerData.txt" example file storing data from cpInstance and csInstance structs**

```
Player
Human
Knight
1.77318
58.6618
21
100
100
100
100
90
0
58.6618
12
0
2
117.324
2
5
5
0
0
```

EDIT. I'll give you an additional part of "character.cpp" with function filling the given structs, as well as this saving them to file.

```
random_device generator;
uniform_real_distribution<double> heightDistribution(1.5, std::nextafter(2, DBL_MAX));
uniform_real_distribution<double> weightDistribution(45, std::nextafter(120, DBL_MAX));
void Character::CreateNewPlayer() {
    Character::CharacterParameters cpInstance;
    Character::CharacterStatistics csInstance;
    char tempRace, tempClass;
    string tempString;
    int tempInt;
    bool isCorrect = false;

    newPlayer->cpInstance.height = heightDistribution(generator);
    newPlayer->cpInstance.weight = weightDistribution(generator);
    newPlayer->csInstance.maxHealth = 100.0;
    newPlayer->csInstance.currentHealth = newPlayer->csInstance.maxHealth;
    newPlayer->csInstance.maxStamina = 100.0;
    newPlayer->csInstance.currentStamina = newPlayer->csInstance.maxStamina;
    newPlayer->csInstance.maxCarryWeight = 90.0;
    newPlayer->csInstance.currentCarryWeight = 0.0;
    newPlayer->csInstance.currentCharacterWeight = newPlayer->cpInstance.weight;
    newPlayer->csInstance.maxSpeed = 12.0;
    newPlayer->csInstance.currentSpeed = 0.0;
    newPlayer->csInstance.basicAcceleration = 2.0;
    newPlayer->csInstance.currentForce = newPlayer->csInstance.currentCharacterWeight * newPlayer->csInstance.basicAcceleration;
    newPlayer->csInstance.modifiedAcceleration = newPlayer->csInstance.currentForce / newPlayer->csInstance.currentCharacterWeight;
    newPlayer->csInstance.basicHealthRegen = 5.0;
    newPlayer->csInstance.basicStaminaRegen = 5.0;
    newPlayer->csInstance.healthRegenBonus = 0.0;
    newPlayer->csInstance.staminaRegenBonus = 0.0;

    do {
        cout << "Please enter your name: "; cin >> tempString;
    } while (tempString.length() > 10);
    newPlayer->cpInstance.name = tempString;
    do {
        cout << "Enter your age: "; cin >> tempInt;
    } while (tempInt > 99);
    newPlayer->cpInstance.age = tempInt;
    cout << "Choose your race (H | V): "; cin >> tempRace;
    while (isCorrect != true) {
        switch (tempRace) {
        case 'H':
        case 'h':
            newPlayer->cpInstance.race = "Human";
            isCorrect = true;
            break;
        case 'V':
        case 'v':
            newPlayer->cpInstance.race = "Vampire";
            isCorrect = true;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "You have selected a wrong character. Please try again.\n";
            cout << "Choose your race (H | V): "; cin >> tempRace;
            break;
        }
    }
    isCorrect = false;
    cout << "Who you want to be (K | M | A): "; cin >> tempClass;
    while (isCorrect != true) {
        switch (tempClass) {
        case 'K':
        case 'k':
            newPlayer->cpInstance.playerClass = "Knight";
            isCorrect = true;
            break;
        case 'M':
        case 'm':
            newPlayer->cpInstance.playerClass = "Mage";
            isCorrect = true;
            break;
        case 'A':
        case 'a':
            newPlayer->cpInstance.playerClass = "Asassin";
            isCorrect = true;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "You have selected a wrong class. Please try again.";
            cout << "Who you want to be (K | M | A): "; cin >> tempClass;
            break;
        }
    }
}

void Character::SaveDataToFile() {
    ofstream playerData;
    playerData.open("playerData.txt");
    playerData << newPlayer->cpInstance.name << endl;
    playerData << newPlayer->cpInstance.race << endl;
    playerData << newPlayer->cpInstance.playerClass << endl;
    playerData << newPlayer->cpInstance.height << endl;
    playerData << newPlayer->cpInstance.weight << endl;
    playerData << newPlayer->cpInstance.age << endl;
    playerData << newPlayer->csInstance.maxHealth << endl;
    playerData << newPlayer->csInstance.currentHealth << endl;
    playerData << newPlayer->csInstance.maxStamina << endl;
    playerData << newPlayer->csInstance.currentStamina << endl;
    playerData << newPlayer->csInstance.maxCarryWeight << endl;
    playerData << newPlayer->csInstance.currentCarryWeight << endl;
    playerData << newPlayer->csInstance.currentCharacterWeight << endl;
    playerData << newPlayer->csInstance.maxSpeed << endl;
    playerData << newPlayer->csInstance.currentSpeed << endl;
    playerData << newPlayer->csInstance.basicAcceleration << endl;
    playerData << newPlayer->csInstance.currentForce << endl;
    playerData << newPlayer->csInstance.modifiedAcceleration << endl;
    playerData << newPlayer->csInstance.basicHealthRegen << endl;
    playerData << newPlayer->csInstance.basicStaminaRegen << endl;
    playerData << newPlayer->csInstance.healthRegenBonus << endl;
    playerData << newPlayer->csInstance.staminaRegenBonus << endl;
    playerData.close();
}
```